# Setting up Ubuntu Router

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, router

I have a fairly standard network set up with a Cisco router with a bunch of public IP addresses connected to a TMG Server Firewall (For the sake of anonymity lets say the public IP of the TMG server is 1.1.1.66 and the IP of the router is 1.1.1.65

We are in the process of setting up a branch office and I have succesfully set up another TMG server with a site-2-site VPN over a spare ADSL line we have in order to check everything works before sending it to the new office.

However, I'd like to mimic various network speeds and latencies to work out what size of connection we need in the branch office and so thought I'd put an Ubuntu Server in between the two and us tc to throttle the bandwidth.

[image: Network Description]

Our ISP has changed the config on the Cisco router so one of the ports has a 172.16.0.1 / 255.255.255.0 VLAN and I have split this range into two 255.255.255.128 ranges and set up and Ubuntu Box to route between them with

- two NICS (72.16.0.2 / 255.255.255.128 and 172.16.0.202 / 255.255.255.128)
- enabled port forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf
- added some simple config to iptables to log every packet

[image]

From the branch firewall and the main firewall I can ping both NIC IP addreses on the Ubuntu Router. And from the Ubuntu Router I can ping everywhere including the 1.1.1.x addresses However I can't ping the two firewalls from each other, its as if the packets aren't being forwarded.  I can't seem to "cross" the ubuntu router.

I suspect its the way I've set up the two NICs with 255.255.255.128 masks but am not really a routing expert!

Answer (score 1):

Have you allowed forwarding?

In `/etc/sysctl.conf` you have to have this *uncommented* line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

After you uncomment this line, you have to use this command:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And you will need add to the route table record about a 1.1.1.x addresses like that:

```
ip route add 1.1.1.0/25 via 172.16.0.1
```

Edit1: You have change netmasks on the firewall2 and router between Ubuntu and firewall to be the same as on the second network adapter:

`172.16.0.1/255.255.255.128` and `172.16.0.2/255.255.255.128`

and

`1.1.1.65/255.255.255.240` and `1.1.1.66/255.255.255.240` (or `128` on the both end)

On the router you have then set, that network `172.16.0.128/255.255.255.128` is reachable via `172.16.0.2`

On the firewall2 you have set, that network `172.16.0.0/255.255.255.0` (it is both networks `127.16.0.0/255.255.255.128` and `172.16.0.128/255.255.255.128`) is reachable via address `1.1.1.65`.